# tikz - create coordinate with maximum y-value of two other coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, calc

I'd like to define a coordinate `(Q1)` which contains the `x`-component of a coordinate `(P1)` and as y-component the maximum y-values of `(P1)` and `(P2)`.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!50, ultra thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);

\coordinate (P1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (P2) at (5,2);

\path let \p1=(P1),\p2=(P2) in coordinate (Q1) at (\x1, max(\y1,\y2));
\path let \p1=(P1),\p2=(P2) in coordinate (Q2) at (\x2, max(\y1,\y2));
%                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

\draw (P1) -- (P2);
\draw[dotted, red] (Q1) -- (Q2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am looking for some kind of replacement for the underlined parts in my example above. I've found `\pgfmathmax` in the pgfmanual, but replacing the underlined parts with `\pgfmathmax{\y1}{\y2}` gives some error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only missing a pair of braces:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!50, ultra thin] (0,0) grid (5,5);

\coordinate (P1) at (0,1);
\coordinate (P2) at (5,2);

\path let \p1=(P1),\p2=(P2) in coordinate (Q1) at (\x1, {max(\y1,\y2)});
\path let \p1=(P1),\p2=(P2) in coordinate (Q2) at (\x2, {max(\y1,\y2)});
%                                                       ^            ^

\draw (P1) -- (P2);
\draw[dotted, red] (Q1) -- (Q2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

When Ti*k*Z looks for coordinates it uses delimited macros, so when you do `(\x1, max(\y1,\y2))` it will look for something between `(` and the next `)`, which is `\x1, max(\y1,\y2`, and things will go weird :). To avoid this you can "hide" the parentheses in braces: `(\x1, {max(\y1,\y2)})`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! now tikz makes a little more sense to me :)

Comment: @thengineer You're welcome :)